# setView not displaying content in dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am not able to display a view inside alertdialog.`new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Set preferences for ")
        .setView(findViewById(R.layout.radiodialog1))
        .show();`
And the radiodialog1 bring `

```
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioNum"
            style="@style/RadioButtonAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="btnNumbersClicked"
            android:text="@string/PlayNumbers" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFour"
            style="@style/RadioButtonAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="btnStart4LetterClicked"
            android:text="@string/btn4LetterText" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFive"
            style="@style/RadioButtonAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="btnStart5LetterClicked"
            android:text="@string/btn5LetterText" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

`

The dialog displays with just the title that is set.. I tried placing this radio group inside a linearlayout. Works fine when setContentView for an activity. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use either,

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.radiodialog1);
```

or Create View by LayoutInflater, and then inflate view from layoutinflater service, then set that view to dialog, by Dialog.setView() method.

Comment: not sure what's wrong.. i tried that as well.. for some reason i don't know findViewById is returning null in this method. But when i try to to get the view in onCreate method I am able to get the id.. can you throw some light on that

Comment: Please understand, findViewById() method is here for Activity, unless you call it with some specific view, and as you dont have R.layout.radiodialog1 in the layout set in the activity, you will get it always null. you can get reference of a layout outside in the activity layout, by using layout inflater.